# CakePHP + Crud "Add" action (POST) returning 412 Precondition Failed

Tags: php, mysql, json, cakephp, crud

The `Add` action (POST method) in CakePHP 3 is not working and it is asking fields that I already informed in json message. Let me explain:

### What is my scenario:

- I'm using WAMP and my Apache is `mod_rewrite` activated;
- I'm using composer and I installed CakePHP 3 and CRUD (friendsofcake/crud);
- I set MySQL database connection correctly;
- I'm using MySQL example database `sakila`;
- I generated `Country` model from Bake;
- I changed the `AppController` class content to load CRUD plugins changing it's content to:

```
namespace App\Controller;

use Cake\Controller\Controller;

class AppController extends Controller {

    use \Crud\Controller\ControllerTrait;

    public $components = [
        'RequestHandler',
        'Crud.Crud' => [
            'actions' => [
                'Crud.Index',
                'Crud.View',
                'Crud.Add',
                'Crud.Edit',
                'Crud.Delete'
            ],
            'listeners' => [
                'Crud.Api',
                'Crud.ApiPagination'
            ]
        ]
    ];
}
```

- I added the Router::extensions(['json', 'xml']) in `app/config/routes.php`;
- I added $routes->resources('Country') without deleting the default routes existing in `app/config/routes.php`;
- My root site address is http://localhost:8080/mtag

### How problem happen:

I'm using [Postman for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop) and setting header `Accept` and `Content-Type` value to `application/json` and sending POST to following link: http://localhost:8080/mtag/country with the following json content:

```
{
  "country": "BlaBlaBla",
  "last_update": "2015-12-24"
}
```

But I receive the following status code: 412 Precondition Failed.
In returned json:

```
success: false,
data: {
  code: 412,
  message: "2 validation errors occured",
}
```

The missing fields indicated is `country` and `last_update` but I informed them in json. What I did wrong? Did someone have an example how to use CakePHP CRUD correctly using json?

Answer (score 0):

When I am using Postman for testing the cakePHP CRUD functions I do NOT use `application/json` for `Content-Type` but leave it blank. And for the body part just use `form-data` instead of a json object while using a `raw` body.

Comment: Still not working. I receive the validation error message. Seems like the json object is not being recognized.

Comment: ok, I guess the problem is that you need to decode your json object in your add function. So I am doing it in a before filter like this: `public function beforeFilter() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $data = $this->request;
          $this->request->data = $this->request->input(function ($data) { 
              return json_decode($data, true); 
          });
    } 
}`

Comment: It works! But if I wish to transform a XML in array, like json_decode?